# How to generate ssh key for git using puttygen

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

How can I generate SSH key for Git or GitLab?

I want to access git from git bash. How can I config ssh key for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Download Puttygen

Open puttyGen -> Go to Key Section -> over your mouse on a key section before that press "Generate" button.
Download Public key and private key and copy text from key section and paste into GitLab

Open puttygen -> load ppk file -> Select conversions menu -> Export OpenSSH key

To save file at {home}/.ssh and give file name "id_rsa" -> Save it

Open Git bash -> go to a folder where to sync git